# Why does my Node.js Socket.IO server emit several messages, altough it just runs once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

**The Problem:**

Look at this code snippet from the server:

```
io.of("/chat").on("connection", socket => {
  socket.on("joinRoom", (room, name) => {
    chatRooms.forEach(chatRoom => {
      console.log(chatRoom);
      if (chatRoom.users.includes(name.toLowerCase())) {
        console.log("hello");

        return socket.emit("err", "Username already been taken");
      } else {
        chatRoom.users.push(name.toLowerCase());
        socket.join(room);
        io.of("/chat")
          .to(room)
          .emit("newUser", "New user has joined the room");
        return socket.emit("success", "Joined room ", room);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

Especially this line: `return socket.emit("err", "Username already been taken");`

I catch it on the client side like this:

`socket.on("err", msg => console.error(msg));`

So on the client I have a simple form. This form emits a "joinRoom" event to the server, provided with the name and room name.

The first time around it's working (because the user is the first to appear in that room). After I click a second time, it emits this error I mention above.

I successfully catch it on the client. But the problem is, the console shows several outputs (take a look at the "2" in the red console.error on the screenshot):

[image]

This is the console output when I want to sign in but has already been taken. I receive the message 2 times. When I click another time it looks like this:

[image]

**So my question is, why does this event get emmited 2 times on the first click and 3 times on the second click (the number gets higher and higher the more I click).**

I know it's not breaking anything, but I just want to understand why it's doing this weird thing.

Thx guys!

Comment: One of the times I have had this was when I was not unsubscribing from events when I navigated away in an SPA. Then when I navigated back, it subscribed again with the on() method. Have you tried changing this to once() to see if it is multiple client bindings rather than multiple server emissions?

Comment: @SeanForman I now catch the error with `.once` and it does the trick. But I still don't know the behaviour. Could you pleaes elaborate in more detail in what you just said? So in detail, every time i click the button I create another error subscription (when I use `on` instead of `once`?

Comment: You may be subscribing to the event multiple times. I would place a console.log("Foo") directly above the first line: io.of("/chat") and see if you are binding to the server multiple times. I would also subscribe to the ondisconnect method on the client side to see if my app had become disconnected from the server at any point. The on("connection") will run every time there is a prolonged internet issue

Comment: @SeanForman I get it now. When I move all my `on` events, to a `componentDidMount` hook, it's also working with `on` and I know why. It's now clear. I just make my "joinRoom" `emit` on the function that runs when I click the button. Thx a ton!